# How to project and scale layer to cartesian (x,y) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, r

I am new to QGIS and I have two layers I want to plot in QGIS but I somehow cannot convert one of them to other projection systems. This is a problem because each layer ends up in a different position and they should overlap:

- Layer one: comes from a .csv and the polygons come in a WKT and are in cartesian format (long, lat). This is the layer that I cannot reproject to other systems.

**EDIT** I just checked and when loading the first layer, QGIS gives a message that says that this layer has no CRS. This confuses me even more...

- Layer two: comes from a .shp file (with its correspondent .prj, .shx, etc.) and  this one I can convert to other projections but I can't get it to Layer One's projection coordinates

How do I solve this? The second layer I downloaded it from the spanish national statistics institute (www.ine.es/en/censos2011_datos/cen11_datos_resultados_seccen_en.htm) , the first one came as a given. Also if someone knows how to do it in R, answers are more than welcome.

Screenshots, note the coordinates that QGIS yields (first image is layer 1, second layer 2):

[image: Layer 1]
[image: Layer 2]

sample data:`ID NOMBRE  PROVINCIA_INE   MUNICIPIO_INE   PROVINCIA_INE_ID    MUNICIPIO_INE_ID    SECCIONES_CENSALES  WKT
0-EU-ES-28-01-020-085   Miraflores de la Sierra Madrid  SOTO DEL REAL   28  28144   2802801001, 2803401001, 2804501016, 2806701001, 2806701002, 2806701003, 2808501001, 2808501002, 2808501003, 2812001001, 2814401001, 2814401002, 2814401003, 2814401004  POLYGON ((-3.799082 40.849834, -3.796926 40.848022, -3.792479 40.848271, -3.790517 40.846764, -3.787734 40.845321, -3.78545 40.838735, -3.774378 40.826942, -3.758486 40.820663, -3.744765 40.808853, -3.744925 40.807285, -3.740955 40.8054, -3.734056 40.805329, -3.732387 40.803447, -3.724855 40.801006, -3.723403 40.798152, -3.725922 40.793204, -3.73773 40.782672, -3.740098 40.777218, -3.737176 40.76905, -3.744816 40.76572, -3.736435 40.757916, -3.722519 40.740666, -3.715269 40.736091, -3.710177 40.729491, -3.717865 40.728543, -3.726083 40.73087, -3.7327 40.730485, -3.732848 40.735456, -3.738881 40.744419, -3.758577 40.758865, -3.759803 40.761586, -3.763947 40.761308, -3.771251 40.763863, -3.783859 40.770073, -3.802624 40.770618, -3.807198 40.777535, -3.811236 40.779251, -3.811895 40.785679, -3.813971 40.786912, -3.813479 40.796021, -3.828123 40.808769, -3.827749 40.814979, -3.830158 40.817935, -3.829713 40.830901, -3.815049 40.841148, -3.815182 40.84314, -3.808855 40.848724, -3.804239 40.849631, -3.802079 40.848544, -3.799082 40.849834))
0-EU-ES-28-01-011-086   El Molar    Madrid  EL MOLAR    28  28086   2800901001, 2805901001, 2808601001, 2808601002, 2808601003, 2810801001, 2810801002, 2812901004, 2814501002, 2816401001, 2816401002, 2816801001  POLYGON ((-3.593485 40.750705, -3.58733 40.748226, -3.582657 40.750591, -3.576659 40.750026, -3.572034 40.743977, -3.561801 40.743847, -3.55564 40.738086, -3.547488 40.734555, -3.54409 40.734615, -3.539326 40.73283, -3.530666 40.734047, -3.525766 40.732757, -3.528184 40.713665, -3.532074 40.711415, -3.544003 40.692216, -3.546959 40.691724, -3.553206 40.687127, -3.555312 40.682785, -3.553432 40.680278, -3.555185 40.668964, -3.554494 40.666867, -3.55023 40.664916, -3.556324 40.662384, -3.555827 40.660775, -3.555775 40.65033, -3.559066 40.650485, -3.566692 40.650369, -3.568148 40.643543, -3.577771 40.645808, -3.584164 40.645122, -3.584663 40.653534, -3.589333 40.655884, -3.593463 40.654804, -3.597052 40.65802, -3.601595 40.669762, -3.601294 40.673301, -3.604856 40.679733, -3.600745 40.696273, -3.60206 40.696628, -3.603361 40.710937, -3.607021 40.715053, -3.608081 40.71439, -3.605649 40.72052, -3.595097 40.725437, -3.591719 40.728969, -3.593485 40.750705))`

Comment: Would it be possible to upload samples of the layers or links to them?

Comment: Uploading sample, links and screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Know the projections of your data (layer 2 has EPSG:3042, layer 1 is unknown)
2. Create a QGIS project, set the projection of the whole project
   **Project --> Project Properties --> CRS --> "Enable on the fly CRS transformation"**
   and select your desired display projection (e.g. EPSG:4326 or EPSG:3042)
3. Set the CRS of your CSV data (which lacks projection information)
   **Right-click the layer --> Properties --> General --> CRS**
   Find& select the appropiate CRS ( I'd start guessing with EPSG:4326)
4. Now you should have both layers visually overlapping thanks to the on-the-fly transformation

You can also reproject your data so you have two sources with the same projection. This way you don't rely on the magical on-the-fly transformation, but have actually modified your data sources, allowing you to continue working with them in whatever tool you prefer.

Comment: I had some problems in my laptop (company owned), I was able to use your solution on my personal laptop. Thanks!